# Recieving NETWORK_ERR:XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 error when using convert API

Tags: javascript, convertapi

I am converting an HTML Document (That is dynamically generated from an API call) and  using Convert API to convert the HTML page to a PDF. This has been working consistently till yesterday when with no code change I started getting this error from convert API:

NETWORK_ERR:XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

I am not sure what this error means and how to rectify this issue.

Comment: it's a network error, likely not due to your code. are you sure the api is still active, and you still have access to the api? It seems this error is commonly thrown with CORS requests when CORS isn't implemented by the server.

Comment: Could you post your full code? ConvertApi support CORS.